# Setting a maximum possible value to a variable C++

Tags: c++, variables

it's supposed to be an easy question, but i couldnt find the answer on google. So, how do i assign a maximum possible value to a variable?
So i want my variable to be no more than 10 as apossible value no matter what

```
int example;
example = ?;
```

Comment: Really depends on the use case.  Can you show how you want to a "limited" `int`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I will have it increase as the user performs an action, but i dont want to increase to more than 10

Comment: @NathanOliver can i set as <= 10?

Comment: @Roomba And what should happen if you *do* increase the number above 10?

Comment: Is an `if` statement not enough to check it when you modify it to make sure you don't exceed your bound?

Comment: @NathanOliver well, lets say i am making an RPG game and i have a Strength stat. This stat is increased by an x amount every time a player hits a monster. But i dont want it to increase to more than 10.

Comment: You probably want to write a class `BoundedValue<0, 10>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I am very new to coding, can i add a class to a variable?

Comment: If you are new, you will want to use if () statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might create a custom class to handle your needs, something like:

```
template <int Min, int Max>
class BoundedValue
{
public:
    BoundedValue(int value = Min) : mValue(Min) { set_value(value); }

    int get_value() const { return mValue; }
    void set_value(int value) {
        if (value < Min || Max < value) {
            throw std::out_of_range("!"); // Or other error handling as clamping
            // value = std::clamp(value, Min, Max);
        }
        mValue = value;
    }

    BoundedValue& operator= (int value) { set_value(value); }

    BoundedValue& operator ++() { set_value(mValue + 1); return *this; }
    BoundedValue operator ++(int) { auto tmp = *this; ++*this; return tmp; }

    // other convenient functions

    operator int() const { return mValue; }

private:
    int mValue = Min;
};
```

And then use it:

```
BoundedValue<0, 10> example;

++example;
example = 11; // "Error"
```